# How to set a min width before word-wrap inside an Asp.net Grid View column iif that columns text is at least certain length. ex 50 words

Tags: c#, html, css, asp.net

...without knowing how many columns the grid view may have or which columns will contain a lot of text. (Auto resize all other columns)

I have a grid view on a webpage that is generated from a database and it displays different columns in different orders depending on the user or user groups. Typically, it is displaying somewhere between 15 and 30 columns. For some user/user groups all of the columns can fit on the screen without any text wrapping too much, for others even after the grid view auto sizes all of the columns to be as small as possible it doesn’t all fit on the screen requiring a horizontal scroll bar and it’s then forcing the columns with large amount of text to wrap after only one or two words.

**I am trying to figure out if there is a way to stop a column from resizing** to a tiny size **if its content is really long and** instead **wrap only after a certain size** (assuming that the content of that column is large enough to require the column to be that “certain size” to begin with) however I can’t know which column is going to have a ton of words since each user / user group can modify which columns they use, which are displayed, and what each column is called.  (So I can’t hard code a specific column to be a minimum/specific width)

**Example**

If for example a column has text that is long than say, 50 words, I want to set that column to only word wrap after at least 4 or 5 words have already been displayed on the first line (or a certain pixel size) But if a column is smaller than that I want the column to become as small as possible so that as many rows / columns can be visible on the screen as possible. I don’t mind the horizontal scroll but I am trying to get the wrapped text to not wrap more than 5 or so lines. (Currently it’s wrapping like 15-30 lines leaving 1 -2 words on a line)

**Example – What I want
UserGroup1**

[This is what I would like to happen (The column with the long text is kept large enough to read multiple words before wrapping](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0hytJ.png)

**Example -- What I’m currently getting** 
UserGroup1 (This only happens to users groups who have a ton of columns, other user groups are able to fit everything on the screen without ridiculous word wrap)

[Example of what I'm currently getting -- Row with lots of columns is word wrapping every word or two causing the row to take up ton of space on the site. (Made image a bit smaller since its so tall)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hBsIr.png)
This User/User group also has so many columns set to display that it has a horizontal scroll making it difficult for users to get to easily read the data.

**Additional Example**

Example of a different user group who has less columns and a different order.

Description
This is an example of a different user/user groups gridview display. This user/user group has chosen to have a lot less columns and all of the columns have no problem fitting on the page. This gridview does not have a horizontal scroll bar and already wraps nicely due to less columns.

This grid view automatically resizes the smaller columns and makes the column with more data bigger because it doesn’t need to try to fit a ton of columns on the page.  This example is similar to the "What I want" example, except it has less columns so the description column is wider.